# How to keep record of cell changing in vba

Tags: vba, excel

**Program Description**  I want this program to msgbox every time when cell is changing. For ex. If i have AAA in row1 and row2 BBB i want my code to recognize when cell is changing from one string to another string.

**Problem** I never used change function before so i don't know where to use it in my code. Can anyone help me out with how to use change function or any other ways to keep track of string changing. Somehow my change function not working.

```
Sub xym()

    Dim x As String, dtext, lastrow As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim rangnum As Range, i As Long
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    Set rangenum = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
    dtext = rangenum.Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(dtext, 1)
        If dtext(i,1).change then msgbox "yes"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Will the change result from user editing or from function execution??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent function execution.... when im going to run macro it will loop through the rows and msgbox every time when cell value is changing

Comment: Are you trying to have this run in real time, for example immediately after someone makes a change to column A? Or, are you trying to have a process whereby you can run an audit at an arbitrary time to see all of the cells that changed at any time in the past?

Comment: @ExcelHero i am trying to loop through the rows and msgbox every time string change for ex. if row 1 aaa and row 2 bbb so row change between 1 n 2.

Comment: Ahh I think I understand now. You want your procedure to iterate through all of the cells in column A of the UsedRange and to dispaly a MsgBox each time there is a difference in value from cell to cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Sub xym()
    Dim i&, v
    With Sheet1.[a1]
        v = .Resize(.Item(.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Row)
    End With
    For i = 2 To UBound(v) - 1
        If v(i, 1) <> v(i - 1, 1) Then
            MsgBox "Yes." & vbLf & "Cell A" & i & " is different."
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Worksheet Change Event - there is a clear explanation of how to use this event on the following page, including how to only respond to changes that happen in certain cells.

**Excel VBA: Automatically Run Excel Macros When a Cell Changes/Enter Data. Worksheet Change Event**
http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm