# Quickest way to note changes that macro makes

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

**Some background:**

I have an Excel Add-In that executes 17 Sub Routines and was wondering what would be the easiest, most efficient, and fastest way to

1. Record specific changes made by the macro
2. Display a list of all the changes (in a new spreadsheet) and why it changed (or flagged/highlighted) each cell
3. Provide the cell address of each error as a clickable link that will take the user to the specific cell in another worksheet (in the same workbook)

**What I've gathered thus far:**

I've read up on a few methods of how to accomplish this, most notably from [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/track-changes.htm), [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/500810-visual-basic-applications-code-track-changes-workbook.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199635/how-to-keep-record-of-cell-changing-in-vba/33202329), and most importantly [here](http://www.marktastic.com/2012/08/how-to-log-activity-in-microsoft-excel/). These suggest methods such as

- Dumping the `UsedRange` into an array prior to running through all the subs, then dumping the `UsedRange` into a second array after all the subs have completed. Compare the two arrays and find the differences that way.
- Utilizing the `worksheet_change` event to log the changes.
- The last link for the [Marktastic site](http://www.marktastic.com/2012/08/how-to-log-activity-in-microsoft-excel/) provides the most convincing method, combining the previous two methods. However, even with his method of checking the array each time the `worksheet_change` event fires takes .06 seconds, which seems like it will add up to a lot of overhead.

**A few particular issues I face include:**

- Dealing with large files (15000+ rows, 150 columns)
- Some of my subs make changes that don't need to be noted, such as only rearranging values in certain cells, not changing them otherwise
- My macro is built to work fast (<1 minute) and complete it's scan of our large files, so I imagine this would eliminate using the `Worksheet_Change` event and also writing immediately to the separate worksheet after each error is addressed accordingly. Even utilizing both methods in one as Mark suggests seems like it'll cause too much lagtime.
- Comparing two arrays appears it would also be quite slow for files as large as I'm working with, as it would mean iterating through 15000 (rows) x 150 (columns) = 2,250,000 cells
- Since I"m making all the changes via a macro the `worksheet_change` event won't fire.

So, that basically eliminates all of the options I've come across. The only other option I can think of is just have one array, use it to record the cell/location and the error in the location as the code is executing and then dump the entire array into the new sheet after the subs complete. Would this really be my best option though?

So, given all of the facts and research above

**Now, for my question:**

- What would be the most efficient way in my situation to record changes and show what (necessary-to-note) changes have been made to the file after my macro has completed? Whether I've listed it or not, feel free to share a method you feel would best suit this situation.
- Can you provide a simple sample code of how to implement your suggested method?

Comment: Please narrow down your question, include your sample code and highlight the problematic part. Best regards,

Comment: I don't see how this could be more narrowed down. I gave a very detailed explanation. I do not have sample code other than the codes included in the links, but if it'll make you happy I'll include them directly on the post. I'm simply looking for advice on how to handle the situation, I don't necessarily need anyone to write code for me. I know that this is not a "*code-writing service*." I'm aware of the rules.

Comment: Your post is more suitable for some discussion forums, not SO. Best regards,

Comment: Well then, please feel free to point me toward one and I'll happily leave.

Comment: Google on "excel forums" returned about 28,300,000 results: plenty options to choose from. Pertinent to this particular site, there is "superuser" option probably better suited for such post. Best regards,

Comment: Ahh very valid point @FlorentB., hadn't even though of that.

Comment: @FlorentB. - I don't know if that is always true. Consider that we have to temporarily suspend event handling in order to avoid a Worksheet_Change run on top of itself when  it writes a value. If event handling has been suspended during 'macro' operation then yes, a Worksheet_Change or Workbook_Sheetchange is not going to pick it up but writing to the worksheet will trigger the event otherwise.

Comment: What method would you suggest I use @Jeeped to accomplish this? I know you mentioned a method to me before, but I don't recall exactly what it was

Comment: @Jeeped, you are right, what I said was very wrong. The Worksheet_Change and Workbook_Sheetchange events are correctly triggered when a cell is updated by code.

Comment: What you're asking has numerous avenues to pursue and any answer would have to take a number of factors in account. A full test environment would have to be setup and numerous 'passes' through the 'macros' should be run to compile a list of potential changes to log. In short, it is beyond the scope of a standard SO question to come up with a comprehensive solution.

Comment: You underestimate the comparing two arrays option.  Just out of curiosity, I compared a 15000 row by 150 column worksheet against itself and it finished in just over 3 seconds.

Comment: Huh, interesting. The only issue I run into then is having to still find a way to record what sort of error was recorded. I guess that means that I would have to call (a function) or write to something (an array) at each instance where a cell has to be changed. @Jeeped I just remembered what you suggested I do to record the changes I want to note. You mentioned something about calling a function after each instance where I'd want to record the cell location. Could you possibly help with a function that I could pass the cell address and reason for the change each time I was to record a change?

Comment: There have been no parameters mentioned; only that you want to record changes. The word 'changes' encompasses a lot of different things. Even at the most rudimentary end of the scale changing a single cell's value is monumentally different than deleting or adding a row or column. A complete list of all possible changes would have to be documented so that each could be dealt with in an appropriate manner as well as a 'fall over' method to try and log anything that does not come into the original criteria. As I stated in an earlier comment, a **full test environment**.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is if I have a function that I can pass a cell reference and reason to I can call that after every error I need to. There's no need to make a list of all errors. Example: I could call some like StoreThisChange(cell address, "Reason") each time I'd like to save the instance. Then somehow I'd be able to output the entire contents of what I've stored using StoreThisChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've decided to go with. Using this method I call a sub each time I want to note a change and pass the necessary variables that I need recorded. In this case, `Cell`,`Reason`,`Status`. Then the sub that has been called stores it at the end of a public `Array`, in this case `ChangeLog`. After I am finished recording all of the changes I need I call the `PrintLog` sub to spit out the list of changes onto a new sheet, which I rename *Change Log*. A neat addition I added was the pre-made `HYPERLINK` formulas I produce while storing the values inside the array. Once the array is pasted to the worksheet the cell references are already clickable links that bring the user to the address on the other worksheet.

```
Public ChangeLog() As String

Sub Test()
    Log ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), "Test1", "Changed"
    Log ActiveSheet.Range("B2"), "Test2", "Needs Attention"
    Log ActiveSheet.Range("C2"), "Test3", "Changed"
    PrintLog
End Sub

Sub Log(Cell As Range, Reason As String, Optional Status As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Not Not ChangeLog) = 0 Then
        ReDim ChangeLog(0 To 2, 0 To 1)
        ChangeLog(0, 0) = "Cells": ChangeLog(1, 0) = "Changes Made": ChangeLog(2, 0) = "Status"
        ChangeLog(0, 1) = "=Hyperlink(" & """#'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Cell.Address(False, False) & """,""" & Cell.Address(False, False) & """)"
        ChangeLog(1, 1) = Reason
        ChangeLog(2, 1) = Status
    Else
        ReDim Preserve ChangeLog(0 To 2, 0 To UBound(ChangeLog, 2) + 1)
        ChangeLog(0, UBound(ChangeLog, 2)) = "=Hyperlink(" & """#'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Cell.Address(False, False) & """,""" & Cell.Address(False, False) & """)"
        ChangeLog(1, UBound(ChangeLog, 2)) = Reason
        ChangeLog(2, UBound(ChangeLog, 2)) = Status
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub PrintLog()
    Dim currentSheet As Integer: currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Index
    For s = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(s).Name = "Change Log" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Worksheets(s).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index))
    WS.Name = "Change Log"
    WS.Tab.Color = vbYellow
    WS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(ChangeLog, 2) + 1, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ChangeLog)
    Erase ChangeLog
    Worksheets(currentSheet).Activate
End Sub
```

Change Log Sheet Preview:
[image: Change Log]